# How to define post response in StrongLoop / LoopBack

Tags: http, post, loopbackjs, strongloop

I've recently tried to make a somewhat simple implementation of a POST HTTP  handler with LoopBack but didn't manage to.
This is the case. When I create a model class it seems that I can only add remote method to implement business functionality. But what if I want to handle the request myself in a proper way in response of a POST request ?
It's not very RESTFul to add special methods with names rather than implementing proper handling of a HTTP verb request. Is there any way to achieve that ?
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to consider [remote hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks) or [operation hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks) in case you want to add some extra logic for your model on top of standard CRUD functionality exposed by automatically generated REST API.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. What I needed exactly was to replace the predefined behavior and Richard's answer totally fited the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own verb and path for the method as follows:

```
MyModel.myMethod = function(...) { ... }

MyModel.remoteMethod('myMethod', {
  accepts: ...,
  returns: ...,
  http: {
    verb: 'post',
    path: '/'
  }
});
```

When would attach the `myMethod` function to the `/api/MyModels/` endpoint.

For further docs on remote methods checkout the following:

- [strongloop docs - remote methods](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Remote+methods)
- [strongloop apidocs - sharedMethod](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/strong-remoting/#sharedmethod)

For the 2nd link, a `sharedMethod` is what gets created when you use the `MyModel.remoteMethod(...)` function.

Comment: Hi, thanks.This is what I missed. In fact, I needed to  'downgrade' my model from 'PersistedModel' to 'Model' to enable my remote function. Otherwise, I was stuck with the conventional behavior of POST method.

Comment: You can also [disable a remote method](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#model-disableremotemethod) if you want all the other `CRUD` methods to remain.